# I created a program for matrix multiplication using pthread But the [0][0] block value always get 0

Tags: c, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];
struct Storage {
    int i,j;
};
void* matThreadMul(void *storage) {
    struct Storage *tempStorage = storage;
    int m;
    int i=tempStorage->i;
    int j=tempStorage->j;
    printf("value of i,j : %d,%d\n", i, j);
    c[i][j]=0;
    for(m=1;m<=3;m++){
        c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][m]*b[m][j]);
    }
    printf("value of c[%d][%d] : %d\n", i,j, c[i][j]);
}
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    struct Storage storage;
    pthread_t thread[3];
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("Enter b[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("****after multiplication****\n");
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        storage.i=i;
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            storage.j=j;
            pthread_create(&thread[j], NULL, matThreadMul, &storage);
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("%d  ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And also suggest me how to pass 2 arguments for `matThreadMul` function in `pthread_create()` method.

I enterd 2 matrics.

```
a= 1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
b= 1 0 0
   0 1 0
   0 0 1
```

and

```
a*b = 0 2 3
      4 5 6
      7 8 9
```

I got `0` instead of `1` in final `a*b` matrices.

Help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: index : `0,1,2` not `1,2,3`

Comment: I tried but same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that strikes is that, in C, arrays start from 0. So when you have an array `a[0]` it has an index 0,1,2.

So your arrays `int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];` have indexes starting from 0. But you are using indexes of 1,2,3. You should change the indexes or in a simpler way, allocate an extra element for each array.

```
int a[4][4],b[4][4],c[4][4];
```

There are 2 other issues with your code.

1. You are creating 9 threads using nested for loops, but during a join you are only joining 3. the best way is to have a 2D array of thread, and use that in create and join.
2. The structure `storage` is reused across all the nine threads. This is not correct, as the threads will run concurrently, and you might change the structure before it is read for a thread. You should again use a 2D array for this structure.

Working code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];
struct Storage {
    int i,j;
};
void* matThreadMul(void *storage) {
    struct Storage *tempStorage = storage;
    int m;
    int i= tempStorage->i;
    int j= tempStorage->j;
    printf("value of i,j : %d,%d\n", i, j);
    c[i][j]=0;
    for(m=0;m<3;m++){
       c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][m]*b[m][j]);
    }
    printf("value of c[%d][%d] : %d\n", i,j, c[i][j]);
}
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    struct Storage storage[3][3];
    pthread_t thread[4][4];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("Enter b[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("****after multiplication****\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            storage[i][j].i=i;
            storage[i][j].j=j;
            pthread_create(&thread[i][j], NULL, matThreadMul, &storage[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      for(j=0; j<3; j++)
      {
        pthread_join(thread[i][j], NULL);
      }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%d  ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro... :D.. I am learning pthread thats why I have lot of confusion in the programming..

Answer (score -2):

You only need to change 3 for 2 and 1 for 0.

Please notice than matrix in C start at index 0. Here you have your code checked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int a[2][2],b[2][2],c[2][2];
struct Storage {
    int i,j;
};
void* matThreadMul(void *storage) {
    struct Storage *tempStorage = storage;
    int m;
    int i=tempStorage->i;
    int j=tempStorage->j;
    printf("value of i,j : %d,%d\n", i, j);
    c[i][j]=0;
    for(m=0;m<=2;m++){
        c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][m]*b[m][j]);
    }
    printf("value of c[%d][%d] : %d\n", i,j, c[i][j]);
}
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    struct Storage storage;
    pthread_t thread[3];
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++){
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("Enter b[%d][%d] : ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("****after multiplication****\n");
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        storage.i=i;
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++){
            storage.j=j;
            pthread_create(&thread[j], NULL, matThreadMul, &storage);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++){
            printf("%d  ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'for(i=0; i<=2; i++)' should be 'for(i=0; i<3; i++)'